# Distributing thousands of files over subfolders

Tags: shell-script, files, zsh

I have a folder `A` with hundreds of thousands of files. I would like to move these files to **new** subfolders `S_i`, with, say, 100 files in each (the last folder may have less than 100 files)

In other words, if my folder `A` has:

```
file1
file2
...
file1000
```

I would later have:

```
S_1:    
    file_1
    ...
    file_100    
S_2:
    file_101
    ...
    file_200
...
```

Before I write a Zsh script manually to do this task (e.g. using variables to count files), I was wondering if there are any readily available tools (like [split](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_%28Unix%29)) that would facilitate this task.

Comment: I think this is the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669176/how-can-i-split-a-folder-with-thousands-of-images-into-multiple-sub-folders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv 'file_(<->)' 'S_$((1 + ($1 - 1) / 100))'
```

If the files are not numbered, but you just want to split that list:

```
n=0; zmv -Q 'file_*(n)' 'S_$((n++/100+1))'
```

`(n)` is to toggle numerical ordering for the list (and you need `-Q` for that globbing qualifier).

Those call one `mv` per file. You can make it a bit more efficient by making `mv` builtin (`zmodload zsh/files`), or you could do:

```
files=(file_*(nN))
for ((n=1; $#files; n++)) {
  mv -- $files[1,100] S_$n
  files[1,100]=()
}
```

The `(nN)` above are `zsh` *globbing qualifiers* which further qualify the glob. `n` is for *numerical* sorting, `N` is to turn on the `nullglob` option for that glob, that is for the glob to expand to an empty list when there is no match.

(with that one, you could even throw in a `mkdir S_$n` in case those directories didn't exist beforehand).

Comment: Thanks! What does `*(nN)` do in the first line of the last example?

Comment: @user27915816, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If the filenames don't contain spaces:

```
i=1;while read l;do mkdir $i;mv $l $((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n100)
```

Using `parallel`:

```
ls|parallel -n100 mkdir {#}\;mv {} {#}
```

Comment: The first one assumes file names don't contain whitespace characters, quotes or backslashes (and if used in shells other than zsh, wildcard characters), don't start with `-`. The second that they don't start with `-` and don't contain newline characters that the braceccl or extendedglob (common) options are not enabled. You'd also want to use `&&` to separate the two commands (and maybe `-p` for `mkdir` to still be successful if the directory already existed beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

There is a linux utility for that dirsplit https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirsplit