# How to move the first x files

Tags: shell, command-line, shell-script, wildcards

I have this huge folder with thousands of unordered files. Is it feasible to move the first 5000s to a subfolder via the `mv` command? For now I move files with

```
 mv *some_pattern* ./subfolder1/
```

As for now, I move images quite randomly, it's not really important if there aren't exactly 5000 files in each subfolder. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: See also [Distributing thousands of files over subfolders](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63265/22565)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move 100 files from a folder containing thousands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/how-to-move-100-files-from-a-folder-containing-thousands)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
mv `ls | head -500` ./subfolder1/
```

Comment: (assuming none of the filenames contain space, tab, newline, star, open square bracket, question mark characters or start with `-` or `.` and assuming `subfolder1` itself does not show up in that list.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if the file contains those, how do we modify the command?

Comment: ```$ sudo mv `ls | head -50000` 01/
sudo: unable to execute /bin/mv: Argument list too long```

Comment: For me in MacOS the solution worked removing the `.`

Something like: `mv `ls | head -500` /subfolder1/`

Comment: Regarding the comment above in dealing with spaces, tabs, etc. This command worked nicely after **changing ``$IFS``**, as my files contained spaces.  <insert eye-roll here>

Comment: mkdir ./subfolder2 | mv `ls *.xml | head -500` ./subfolder2/

Answer (score 19):

With `zsh` and its [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
mv -- *(D.oN[1,5000]) ./subfolder1
```

To move up to 5000 regular files in the order they are in the directory.

For the first 5000 in the lexicographically sorted list:

```
mv -- *some_pattern*(D.[1,5000]) ./subfolder1
```

If you get an error about *arg list too long*. You can use `zsh`'s buitin `mv` command by issuing:

```
zmodload zsh/files
```

first.

POSIXly:

```
set --
for f in .*some_pattern* *some_pattern*; do
  [ "$#" -lt 5000 ] || break
  [ -f "$f" ] || continue
  [ -L "$f" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "$f"
done
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || mv -- "$@" subfolder1/
```

On a GNU system, you could also do:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -name '*some_pattern*' -type f -print0 |
  head -zn 5000 |
  xargs -r0 mv -t ./subfolder1 --
```

Comment: The POSIX snippet is a gem

Comment: what if i get the error using bash?

Comment: Can you point me somewhere to understand what’s going on in the `-- *(D.oN` part? Thanks!

Comment: @karkraeg see edit with link to [zsh's glob qualifiers documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers)

Answer (score 15):

A version that is simple and supports special chars, spaces, etc.

```
ls -Q dir1 | head -1000 | xargs -i mv dir1/{} dir2/
```

For this to work as-is `dir2` must exist and you have to execute it from the parent directory of `dir1` and `dir2`.

This will move 1000 files from dir1 to dir2.

Comment: nice one!
```ls -Q -S dir1 | head -1000 | xargs -i mv dir1/{} dir2/```                             
for moving 1000 largest files in dir1 (-S lists file by size)

Comment: Note that `ls -Q` does not produce an output compatible with `xargs`'s expected input format. It helps for file names containing space characters, but not for double quotes or backslashes and harms for file names containing control characters including TAB.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to the directory which you want to move files from.
2. Run below command:

   ```bash
   find . -name 'Hello*.gz' | head -n 5000 | xargs -d $'\n' mv -t /data01/path/
   ```

In the `find` command, `.` (dot) denotes current directory

Finds files which start with `Hello` and end with `.gz`, first 5,000 files will be moved to `/data01/path/`.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to do something like this:

```
x=1
for file in *
do
    if [ "X$x" = "X#####" ]; then
        break
    fi
    mv $file <destination>
    x=`expr $x + 1`
done
```

This script works in bash, ksh, sh and multiple UNIX variants.

Comment: (provided none of the filenames contain space, tab, newline, star, open square bracket, question mark characters or start with - or . and provided `destination` itself does not show up in that list.)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas True.  This is not a complete solution just a method of dealing with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to succesfully do a move of 50,000 without the mv bash error like this

```
 ls | head -50000 | xargs -I{} sudo mv {} 01/
```

Funny enough, this was on a samba share, so the 50k limit is because Windows Explorer GUI does not like more than 60k files in a dir in general.

Comment: Yes solve error `zsh: argument list too long: mv` in my case `ls i | head -500000 | xargs -I {} mv i/{} o/{}`

Answer (score 2):

Version working even in extremely large directories: moving thousand files from directory containing half million:

```
ls -U . | head -1000 | xargs mv -t 01/
```

(Note that the syntax with {} is spawning new mv for every file, while this one doesn't)